# Можно ли сократить код?

Tags: php

Меня интересует можно ли сократить повторяющуюся проверку условий:

**Дано:**  массив с товарами и 3 статусами прямо в записи (Новинка, Акция, Топ продаж) (так надо).

**Нужно:** распределить товары по их статусам.

**Делаю:**

```
// Получаем товары
$result = get_array(); //не суть важно 

// Статичные фильтры заполняем сразу
$filter_data = [
    "is_new" => [
        "title" => getval("STR_STATUS_NEW"),
        "products" => []
    ],
    "is_act" => [
        "title" => getval("STR_STATUS_ACT"),
        "products" => []
    ],
    "is_top" => [
        "title" => getval("STR_STATUS_TOP"),
        "products" => []
    ]
];

// Заполняем по старинке через цикл
foreach($result as $filter){
    if(!empty($filter["is_new"])){
        $filter_data["is_new"]["products"][$filter["id"]] = $filter["id"];
    }
    if(!empty($filter["is_act"])){
        $filter_data["is_act"]["products"][$filter["id"]] = $filter["id"];
    }
    if(!empty($filter["is_top"])){
        $filter_data["is_top"]["products"][$filter["id"]] = $filter["id"];
    }
    unset($filter);
}
```

**Хочу:** обойтись без цикла

**Пытаюсь:**

```
// Проверяем наличие ключа $filter_data у каждой записи
function checkArray($product,$filters){
    foreach($filters as $key => $value){
        if(!empty($product[$key])){
            $filters[$key]["products"][$product["id"]] = $product["id"];
        }
        unset($key,$value);
    }
}

// Тестим
foreach($result as $filter){
    $filter_data = array_map("checkArray",$filter,$filter_data);
    unset($filter);
}
```

**Итог:**

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Потому что мы потеряли ключи у массива *$filter_data*? (нигде не нашел, что array_map сбрасывает ключи)

**Вопрос:** как быть и нужно ли делать что-то подобное?

**UPD**

Коллега подсказал решение - использовать *array_reduce*

```
$filter_data = array_reduce(
    $result,
    function ($filter_data,$product) {
        foreach($filter_data as $key => $value){
            if(!empty($product[$key])){
                $filter_data[$key]["products"][$product["id"]] = $product["id"];
            }
            unset($key,$value);
        }
        return $filter_data;
    },
    $filter_data
);
```

Однако громоздкая анонимная функция сбивает меня с толку) Понятно, что ее можно вынести, но нужно ли? Хотелось бы также увидеть "правильные" решения. Я просто впервые пытаюсь писать такое.

Comment: И вместо одного цикла стало два. Нормально обошелся.

Comment: @u_mulder ну второй здесь оправдан

Comment: Первый код читабелен, в нем ясно что происходит, а вот как в итоге будет выглядеть второй и будет ли понятно что происходит в нем - это вопрос. И называйте уже продукты продуктами, а не фильтром, это реально сбивает с толку.

Comment: и `$filter['id']` вынесите в `$pId`, не понимаю людей, которые способны по 6 раз писать такое.

Comment: С последними комментами согласен. Код не оптимизирован, потому что пишется первый раз, на пробу))

Comment: Можно еще рекурсию юзнуть. За место множества вложенных циклов.

Comment: Верните на место первоначальный вариант. Его намного проще и читать и поддерживать. Если его и нужно рефакторить, то не "сокращением".

Comment: @vp_arth вняв советам, последовал ответу от пользователя Ипатьев) Получается что в сахаре смысла нет особого

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никогда не нужно прыгать через голову. 
Казалось бы, задача простая и понятная - запихнуть три условия в цикл. И откуда в решении появились функции, синтаксический сахар для циклов и прочая требуха. почему нельзя тупо схлопнуть три условия в цикл, *и на этом остановиться*?

```
foreach($result as $product) {
    foreach ($filter_data as $key => $filter) {
        if(!empty($product[$key])){
            $filter_data[$key]["products"][$product["id"]] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Я убрал $product["id"] из значений, поскольку в дублировании ключа не вижу смысла

Да, и на всякий случай поясню очевидное. Всякие магические заклинания типа "array_filter", "array_reduce" и прочий синтаксический сахар не являются некоей волшебной заменой циклов. **Это те же самые циклы**, только в красивой обертке. Не существует магического способа перебрать все элементы массива без цикла. Когда страус втыкает голову в песок и перестает видеть хищника, это не значит, что хищник перестает видеть страуса. Когда мы упаковываем цикл в вызов функции, он не исчезает.

В общем, если покороче, то написав внутри array_filter внутри foreach вы получаете тот же самый цикл в цикле.

Comment: Стараюсь обходиться без лишних вложенных циклов, хотя иногда приходится

Comment: я за `&$filter`

Comment: @DaemonHK В каком смысле, "стараюсь избегать"? Во-первых, откуда такая идея вообще, а во-вторых, ТРИ вложенных цикла в вашем собственном решении как-то не вяжутся с этим заявлением

Comment: @Ипатьев я просто не теоретик ни разу, чтобы вычислять когда и сколько жрет памяти каждая итерация. Понятное дело, что легче всего запустить по старинке и пойти дальше, но хотелось бы узнать когда стоит и нужно применять всякие array_map, array_filter, array_reduce, дабы не городить "циклы в циклах"

Comment: циклы не жрут память. а приведенные функции в целом не заменяют циклы в циклах. они заменяют только один цикл.

Comment: @DaemonHK читайте дополнение к ответу

Comment: в чем основное преимущество функций - они сделают код понятнее (мб будет небольшой прирост по производительности, но на практике не ощутимый). Можно не вникая в тело функции из ее названия сразу понять, какую логику мы реализуем. преобразование массива в другой  вид, фильтрацию и т.п. В некоторых случаях эти функции в т.ч. можно вызывать без аргументов, и получать некоторый результат без написания кода.

Comment: Можно ещё на спичках сэкономить поменяв циклы местами: в цикле по короткому массиву перебирать массив бОльшего размера.